# How do I install TA-lib in python 3 in Mac OS High Sierra?

Tags: python

My question is how to install TA-lib into python. I have tried and it did not work.

Comment: Can you provide what you tried and the error it returned?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `computer-science` - kindly do not spam the tags (removed).

Answer (score 16):

I was able to get it install via the instructions [here](https://mrjbq7.github.io/ta-lib/install.html). Note that you'll need to

`brew install ta-lib` first. If you don't have HomeBrew, you'll need to go [here](https://brew.sh/). After that, you should be able to `pip install TA-Lib`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apple laptop with M1 chipset you also need to export your inc and lib paths.

```
export TA_INCLUDE_PATH="$(brew --prefix ta-lib)/include"
export TA_LIBRARY_PATH="$(brew --prefix ta-lib)/lib"
```

as described [here](https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib#mac-os-x)